# Where can I find the source code for WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, security

I need to check implemented code for `WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity`.

Can I see implemented code for `WebSecurity` online? (It's an open source class)

Comment: Maybe you can try: [dotPeek from JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)

Comment: The decision to close is more likely to solicit argument, debates and extended discussion in my view. The question has a definitive answer as provided by Filip W.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure, the code for  `WebMatrix.WebData` is open source

Here is the link to `WebSecurity` class - https://github.com/aspnetwebstack/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/WebMatrix.WebData/WebSecurity.cs

Answer (score 3):

The official source code is located on the project's CodePlex Git repo:
https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/WebMatrix.WebData/WebSecurity.cs

The code on GitHub is unfortunately a clone, and is generally not up-to-date.